# How to optimize a program for a small resolution screen?

Tags: optimization, screen, resolution

I'm using C# (and .Net 4) to build a simple desktop program that will be used at a charity event, with a projector screen.
It will be ran on a 10'' screen computer, projecting the screen on the wall, and I need to optimize fonts and images so they look as good as possible.
The projector resolution is 800x600 and the computer that will run the program has a 1024x600 max screen resolution.

I'm a bit confused... I started by making all the windows in my program 800x600, but then when I run it on the computer, there's a lot of wasted space on the sides (since it's 1024px).

I've always been sooo bad at resolutions! Any help on how to optimize my program will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "Optimize" might be the wrong word here.  Also, the problem you're having is kind of vague here, do you have any screenshots that would make it easier to help?

Comment: set your display (or at least one of them) to 800 * 600. Make sure you  have the same font size as well.